# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword gives "com.google.firebase.auth not found"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase as baackend for my android studio. And also fallowed eatch and every step provided by firebase console. I created 3 Activity's

1. MainActivity
2. LoginActivity
3. RigisterActivity

I am able to register the user successfully but when i try to login user with email and password task is not getting successful. below is my code

Android monitor is giving the following error

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

**Login Activity**

```
  private EditText mLoginEmailField;
    private EditText mloginPassField;

    private Button mLoginbtn;
    private Button mNewAccountbtn;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRefrence;





    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mLoginEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmailField);
        mloginPassField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPasswordField);

        mLoginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mNewAccountbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newAccountbtn);
        mDatabaseRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        mNewAccountbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent rigisterIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                rigisterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(rigisterIntent);
            }
        });


        mLoginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void CheckLogin() {

        String email = mloginPassField.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = mloginPassField.getText().toString().trim();


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){


            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        CheackUserExsists();

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Erorr Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    private void CheackUserExsists() {

        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabaseRefrence.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                    Intent MainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    MainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(MainIntent);
                }else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"You need to setup your Account.. ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


                @
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `onComplete()` method to log the reason for sign-in failure:

```
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                CheackUserExsists();
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                // Or if you don't use Log:
                // System.out.println("Sign-in Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Erorr Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The possible reasons for failure are:

- The email address is malformed
- Sign-in by email/password is disabled
- The user account corresponding to the email does not exist or has been deleted
- The user account corresponding to the email has been disabled
- The password is wrong
- The user's token is not valid

The warning message about

> Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

is not significant and is not the reason for the sign-in failure.

Comment: Thank you after i am using the fallowing code"System.out.println("Sign-in Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());" . I am getting the fallowing error: Sign-in Failed: The email address is badly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused android did not find  the dependency for firebase auth. Go to the gradle.build file of the app and insert the dependency. e.g

```
dependencies {
...
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:x.x.x' 

}
```

instead of `x.x.x` add the the version that you need.

For more information go to this resource: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth.