# I Can't Finish my Registration. I'm always getting "Registration Error"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is the program

> MainActivity.java

I am having the problem where it says "Registration Error".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button buttonSignup;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignin;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));

    }

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    textViewSignin =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignin);

    buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewSignin.setOnClickListener(this);

}


private void registerUser() {
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User");
    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == buttonSignup) {
        registerUser();
    }

    if (v == textViewSignin) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
    }
}
```

I am using firebase-auth:10.2.0

And none of the Toast messages appear after I hit the "Register User" button.

Comment: Modify your `onComplete()` method to log the reason for sign-in failure.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39651068/4815718

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

In onCreate() method:

```
   firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
        finish();

}
```

2. When click Registration Button:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
              hideProgressDialog();
               if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Error",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                                 } else {
   Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, PrifileActivity.class);
                                     startActivity(intent);
                                     finish();
                                 }
                             }
                         });
```

Comment: Thanks.. but when i click "Register User" button, it is not going to "ProfileActivity".. why?

Comment: Did you add permission in your project in Firebase?

Comment: What permission? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Go to Console - >  Your project -> Authentication -> Input method -> Enable registration by Email;