# Unable to successfully complete authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the following code, I am trying to open a Login page. User will fill in email and password. When user clicks on login button, `checkLogin` method is called.

I understand that in the `onComplete` method, the 1st if block checking success (filling in email, password and clicking login) is not called. I always get the Toast message "Error login" (the else block).

```
package com.awani.pocketblog;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mLoginEmailField;
    private EditText mLoginPasswordField;
    private Button mLoginButton;
    private Button mNewAccountButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);

        mLoginEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmailField);
        mLoginPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPaswordField);
        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mNewAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newAccountButton);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                checkLogin();

            }
        });
    }

    private void checkLogin() {

        //retrieve the data from database to check if user is logged in correctly

        String email = mLoginEmailField.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mLoginPasswordField.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mProgress.setMessage("Checking Login...");
            mProgress.show();

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
                    //the following if block is never executed....WHY?
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        checkUserExist();

                    } else {
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    private void checkUserExist() {

        //retrieving UID
        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        //check if the user with thi UID already  exists
        mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {

                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);

                } else {
                    Intent setUpIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SetUpActivity.class);
                    setUpIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(setUpIntent);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `task.getException().getMessage()` to the toast for login failure.  Possible reasons for failure are listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39651068/4815718

Comment: @BobSnyder I added the line you suggested above  the code line                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();But it did not change anything :(

Comment: What is the failure message text in the toast?

Comment: @BobSnyder thank you for the answer :).it says ' E/MyActivity: Sign-in Failed: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.'
Turns out that it is trying to search user in database.But for a new user ,there will always be this error...what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authentication with email/password, the user must first be created with [createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Tries to create a new user account with the given email address and
>   password. If successful, it also signs the user in into the app

This example is provided in Step 4 of the [guide for password-based authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth):

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks ,Bob!a confusion though:getCurrentUser() checks for the users already present in the auth library or it just considers the user who is currently typing the info?

Comment: @RamK: `getCurrentUser()` returns the currently signed-in user or null if there is none

Answer (score 0):

Go to your firebase console, enable sign-in method: `Email/Password` or `Anonymous`

[image]

If it does not work, please edit your password, maybe it's too short.